# Use of bootstrap in clustering algorithms

Tags: clustering, bootstrap, k-means

Are there clustering algorithms that take advantage of bootstrap?

For example can one combine bootstrap with a standard K-Means algorithm to scale K-Means.

I was thinking if the following at a high-level:

1. Use bootstrap to create sub-samples from the elements that need to be clustered.
2. Each of these sub-samples should be the size that K-Means scale
3. K-Means each sub-sample in parallel
4. Use the co-occurrence of elements in clusters to extract clusters from the larger population

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're still interested in applying **bootstrap** approach to *clustering*, I would recommend you to read the following two excellent and IMHO relevant answers: one on *applying bootstrapping to clustering* (https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/11702/31372) and another on *determining optimal number of clusters and more* (https://stackoverflow.com/a/15376462/2872891). In addition to some *fit measures*, mentioned in the above-referenced answers, I'd also suggest to use *AIC* and/or *BIC*, as described in answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15839774/2872891), with more details [here](http://sherrytowers.com/2013/10/24/k-means-clustering).

There is a significant amount of **research literature** on using bootstrapping in clustering (for example, see [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0031320387900811) and [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167947311003215)). Despite being beyond my current knowledge level, interest and the scope of this answer, I would like to point to two specifically interesting resources. [This paper](http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~davidson/Publications/IEEEWorkshop.pdf) on using *bootstrapping* for **speeding up** K-means clustering might be also of interest, but requires "manual" implementation. [This blog post](http://aliquote.org/memos/2011/05/22/using-bootstrap-in-cluster-analysis) seems to me interesting and relevant to the topic as well.

As a side note, I would recommend you to take a look at an **alternative** (non-*K-means*) **approach** to clustering, called *model-based clustering*, as implemented in `mclust` R package. The approach, methods and software are described in the paper *"mclust Version 4 for R: Normal Mixture Modeling for Model-Based Clustering, Classification, and Density Estimation"* by Chris Fraley, Adrian E. Raftery, T. Brendan Murphy and Luca Scrucca: http://www.stat.washington.edu/research/reports/2012/tr597.pdf.

Comment: [This question and answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/43185/31372) might also be of interest.

Comment: @user1172468: You are very welcome! Glad you liked it.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, it will be good enough to run k-means on a *single* sample.

So yes, one can combine k-means with sampling, in two ways:

1. run k-means on the sample, and use the result.
2. run k-means on the sample, use the resulting centers, and continue on the full data set (which should usually converge within a small number of iterations now).

I'm not convinced that repeating the process with multiple samples is essential, or that performing a more complex sampling helps. It's a best practise to run it multiple times, and it may work well to use different samples then each time.